# Flutter RaisedButton covering TextField

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `TextField` in my app that's immediately followed by a `RaisedButton`.

When I type in that `TextField`, the button is moved up to be just above my keyboard. If I scroll all the way down in the `TextField`, I can see all of the text. However, when I'm typing and go to a new line, it doesn't scroll all the way down, and the button covers part of the last line of text.

How can I make sure that the full line of text is always visible when I'm typing?
Ideally I'd like the button not to be above the keyboard when I'm typing but rather hidden by it.
If it's easier, though, I'd also be fine with a solution that ensures the `TextField` is scrolled all of the way down.

Here's the (simplified) relevant piece of my app:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Title')),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(child: new Container(
          child: new TextField(
            maxLines: null,
            controller: textController,
          ),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        )),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _myFunction(context),
          child: new Center(child: new Text('Save'))
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Adding

> margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),

in Expanded Widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Title')),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(child: new Container(
           margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
          child: new TextField(
            maxLines: null,
            controller: textController,
          ),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        )),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _myFunction(context),
          child: new Center(child: new Text('Save'))
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```